# Putting Result of Sum function Into Variable Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a subroutine which sums variable rows. I need to take the result of these two sums and sum them, placing the result (and caption) elsewhere on the same worksheet. The method I tried using was capturing the last row for each if the two columns being summed, do the summation, then (I thought) putting the resultant values into two variables I can process later. The code is:

```
Dim LastRowD As Long 
Dim LastRowF As Long
Dim ValD As Long
Dim Valf As Long

LastRowD = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowF = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)(2, 1)
    .Clear
    .Formula = "=SUM(D2:" & .Offset(1, 0).Address & ")"
End With

ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas = False
With ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)(2, 1)
    .Clear
    .Formula = "=SUM(F2:" & .Offset(-1, 0).Address & ")"
End With

ValD = Cells(LastRowD + 1, "D").Value
ValF = Cells(LastRowE + 1, "F").Value
```

When I inspect the values of VALD and VALF, they are both empty. When you view the sheet, the cells have the VALUE of the summation; the formula bar shows the formula. How do I get the values of the cells into the two variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead to capture the values:

```
With ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)(2, 1)
    .Clear
    .Formula = "=SUM(D2:" & .Offset(1, 0).Address & ")"
    ValD = .Value
End With

ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas = False
With ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)(2, 1)
    .Clear
    .Formula = "=SUM(F2:" & .Offset(-1, 0).Address & ")"
    ValF = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Did not realize variable could be 'inserted' like that!